# Remove autocomplete from text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I apologize if it overlaps with other themes, but look who's the best way to remove autocomplete on text input. Is it more appropriate to do it with an HTML or use JavaScript.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: call the destroy method, if you are using jquery ui autocomplete like `$('#input').autocomplete('destroy')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The the easiest way is to add: autocomplete="off"

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion